# I want to buy 500,000 rupees' worth of sound speaker systems from India

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, bangladeshi-citizens

[image: This is picture of the items i wanted to import from india]

Can I import these items from India to Bangladesh free, or do I have to pay tax, and how much would I have to pay?
The value is 500,000 Indian rupees. I am from Bangladesh.

Comment: You have to pay duty when you import goods from other countries. Try http://bangladeshcustoms.gov.bd/trade_info/duty_calculator

Comment: 5 lakh = around US$6,000. That’s typically above the personal import allowance regardless of the country.

Comment: Í would very much recommend buying those in Bangladesh directly. I can't understand the acronyms, but it seems very likely that duty on loudspeaker is 58.6% + 20% VAT...

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you contact Bangladesh customs directly. Make sure you know the country of manufacture.

I see a 58.6% rate which appears to include 15% VAT and 25% import duty but there are a number of taxes that make that rate up, some of which are imposed for commercial importation (AIT=Advance Income Tax, for example). Typically it can also vary with country of manufacture (not where you're importing it from if that's different), according to free trade deals which could lower the taxes or in some cases taxes may be higher from other countries for one reason or another.

- CD = Customs Duty
- RD = Regulatory Duty
- SD = Supplementary Duty
- VAT =  Value Added Tax
- AT = Advance Tax
- AIT = Advance Income Tax

HS number is probably one of:

85182100    Single Loudspeakers, Mounted In Their Enclosures    58.6%

85182200    Multiple Loudspeakers, Mounted In The Same Enclosure 58.6%

Rates from the [link](https://bangladeshcustoms.gov.bd/trade_info/duty_calculator) that @hilmar provided above (58.6% total)

[image]

It's unclear to me how these add up to 58.6%. If they are all applicable in your case and all compounded the rate is more than 63%.

When import taxes are this high, sometimes locally procured products have a lower cost because they're imported by some other means or the declared value is different (perhaps wholesale level pricing, or perhaps cheating).